# Shuffle a string to not contain identical adjacent letters

Tags: c#, arrays, string, sorting, shuffle

I have to write a program which shuffles the letters of an user inputed string in order to not contain 2 identical adjacent letters. If this is not possible, the program should return the letter that occured the most.( Without using LinQ).

```
For the input: tttesst
```

The output should be:

```
tetstst
```

For the input:`aaaabc`
The output should be: `a`

```
using System;

string example = "tttesst";

var orderList = SortArray(example.ToCharArray());

string lettersString = string.Empty;
for (int i = 0; i < orderList.Length; i++)
{
    lettersString += orderList[i];
    if (i + 1 == orderList.Length)
    {
        break;
    }

    if (orderList[i] != orderList[i + 1])
    {
        lettersString += " ";
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(lettersString);
Console.ReadLine();
static char[] SortArray(char[] array)
{
    int length = array.Length;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < length; j++)
        {
            if (array[i] > array[j])
            {
                char temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    return array;
}
```

This is what I tried but the output is:`e ss tttt`. How can I combine these substrings of grouped identical letters into a string that does not have adjacent letters?

Comment: If there's no random element, it's not a "shuffle". It's an arrangement.

Comment: It can be random if there are multiple possibilities of arrangements available.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you get the always district string and no adjacent character.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ShuffleString
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Shuffle("aaaaabc"));
        }

        static string Shuffle(string input)
        {
            // Convert the input string to a char array
            char[] inputArray = input.ToCharArray();

            // Shuffle the char array
            Random rng = new Random();
            int n = inputArray.Length;
            while (n > 1)
            {
                n--;
                int k = rng.Next(n + 1);
                char value = inputArray[k];
                inputArray[k] = inputArray[n];
                inputArray[n] = value;
            }

            // Rebuild the string, skipping any characters that are the same as the previous character
            string shuffledString = "";
            char previousChar = '\0'; // use a null char as the initial value for previousChar
            foreach (char c in inputArray)
            {
                if (c != previousChar)
                {
                    shuffledString += c;
                    previousChar = c;
                }
            }

            return shuffledString;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't believe @Racula123 is trying to remove duplicate letters here. I believe the intention is to sort the string so that no two adjacent letters are equal (which would imply duplicate letters are acceptable, just not next to each other), unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: I don't want to remove the duplicates. I want to rearrange the string to not have adjacent identical letters, but keeping it's length.

Comment: @cdbullard yes you are right. I modified the code.

Comment: The output would be the same as the input for the modified code.

Comment: @Raluca123 try now. I think your question is bit confusing. Above code will solve first part.

Comment: The idea is that the shuffled string needs to be the same length as the inputed one. If there is no possibility to shuffle the string and not have adjacent identical letters, the code should return the letter with the most occurences, in the case above 'a'.  PS: I'm not allowed to use LinQ.